# LLVMVerifyFunction: Instruction does not dominate all uses

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

What's wrong with following snippet? I'm getting "Instruction does not dominate all uses" in `LLVMVerifyFunction`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>

int main() {
    LLVMModuleRef module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("test");
    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();

    LLVMTypeRef params = LLVMDoubleType();
    LLVMTypeRef type = LLVMFunctionType(
                                        LLVMDoubleType(),
                                        &params,
                                        1,
                                        0);

    LLVMValueRef function = LLVMAddFunction(module, "foo", type);
    LLVMSetLinkage(function, LLVMExternalLinkage);

    LLVMValueRef param = LLVMGetParam(function, 0);
    LLVMSetValueName(param, "a");

    LLVMDumpValue(function);

    LLVMValueRef one = LLVMConstReal(LLVMDoubleType(), 1);
    LLVMValueRef instr = LLVMBuildFAdd(builder, param, one, "addtmp");

    LLVMBasicBlockRef block = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(function, "entry");
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, block);
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, instr);

    // Verify function.
    if (LLVMVerifyFunction(function, LLVMPrintMessageAction) == 1) {
        LLVMDeleteFunction(function);
        printf("bad");
    }

    LLVMDisposeBuilder(builder);
    LLVMDisposeModule(module);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer would be more obvious if you include the IR you generate instead of the code you're using. Anyway, I'm guessing the issue is that you should only insert the `fadd` instruction after you've created the basic block and set the builder's insert point.

Comment: Here's the generated IR: declare double @foo(double)

Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %addtmp = fadd double %a, 1.000000e+00
  ret double %addtmp

Comment: I mean the generated IR for the whole module, not just the error.